# Collection properties are lost when exporting in google earth engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, fields-attributes

I have a general confusion over the 'id' field and how it is set and change in GEE, but I faced another strange thing: The collection properties are lost when exporting in GEE! I tried below sample code:

```
var features = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(30.41, 59.933), {name: 'Voronoi'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-73.96, 40.781), {name: 'Thiessen'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(6.4806, 50.8012), {name: 'Dirichlet'})
]);
features = features.set({'test_property':'Test'});
Export.table.toAsset({
  collection: features,
  description:'vectorsToAssetExample',
  assetId: 'exampleAssetId'
});
```

I can see `'test_property'` and can not see any `'id`' field by print(features), but  when I import `'exampleAssetId'`, I have an `'id'` field and instead of `'test_property'` in the properties, I have `'system:asset_size'` property.
How can I have my properties retained when exporting?